# How to combine like and between in same statement (laravel Query Builder/model)

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-7

Following are the HDD column from the Computer model (I know it's not a good format to store data  but it's already stored like that)

```
     HDD
4x2TBSATA2
2x2TBSATA2
8x2TBSATA2
4x1TBSATA2
2x120GBSSD
4x480GBSSD
```

I want to fetch the range out of HDD column where storage is in a specific range, for example, fetch storage between 120GB to 1TB should output

```
4x1TBSATA2
2x120GBSSD
4x480GBSSD
```

I was wondering if it's possible to combine like and between in the same statement?

I tried the following which doesn't work.

```
select * from `server_details` where `HDD` between '%120GB%' and '%10TB%'

select * from `server_details` where `HDD` between "Like '%120GB%'" and "LIKE '%10TB%'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use between with wildcard queries. You *might* be able to write a regular expression to match what you need, for example:

```
select * from `server_details` where `HDD` regexp '1[2-9]\dGB|[2-9]\d\dGB|\dTB|10TB'
```

but as you can see this is a very specific expression based on what you've written and each different limit will need a different expression.

There's [some python code](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/534137/) to generate such an expression but no PHP code that I could find (with some very basic googling)

Another solution (and what I would personally recommend) is to add the capacity as a separate column:

Migrate your current table:

```
class AddCapacityColumnMigration extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('computers', function (Blueprint $table) {
             $table->bigInt('capacityMB')->nullable();
        });
        Computer::chunk(100, function ($computers) {
            foreach ($computers as $computer) {
                if (preg_match('/(\d+)x(\d+)(M|G|T)B/',$computer->HDD,$m) {
                    $capacity = $m[1];
                    $capacity *= $m[3] === 'M' ? 1 : ($m[3] === 'G' ? 1000 : 1000000 );
                    $computer->capacityMB = $capacity * $m[2];
                    $computer->save();
                }
            }
       });
    }
```

Then you might want to add a `creating` and `updating` event in your model to ensure you always set the new  capacityMB column. When all this is done your query is as simple as:

```
select * from `server_details` where `capacityMB` between 120000 and 10000000
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do just in SQL, extract the size part, convert it to a number, and compare.

```
select *,
  cast(`HDD` as unsigned)*
  cast(substr(`HDD`,LOCATE('x',`HDD`)+1) as unsigned)*
  (case when`HDD` LIKE '%TB%' then 1000 else 1 end) as GB
from `server_details`
where
  cast(`HDD` as unsigned)*
  cast(substr(`HDD`,LOCATE('x',`HDD`)+1) as unsigned)*
  (case when`HDD` LIKE '%TB%' then 1000 else 1 end)
  between 120 and 10000;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the database, in **HDD** column, you should not store alpha-numeric values like 120GB, 10TB, you should store numeric values like 120, 10000. Please try with the following query.

```
$hdds = DB::table('server_details')
           ->whereBetween('HDD', [120, 10000])
           ->get();
```